Odometry is not initialized with robot's pose in simulation
We are transitioning from gazebo classic to ignition (gz harmonic + ros2 humble). We found that the odometry value is not initialized with the initial robot's pose in the simulated world. Odometry is updated when the robot moves but it always starts at (0,0,0).
We are using the differential drive plugin and ros2 control. We have tested the problem in standard models provided with ignition (visualize_lidar.sdf, diff_drive.sdf)
Do we need to make gazebo publish the robot's pose? if yes, How?
Any help will be appreciated!
